# Setting a lazy reference to a django serializer class

Tags: python, django

I have two models which has a field reference to each other.
Both were in seperate files, but i decided to put them in a single file to avoid circular import bugs.

However, unlike making a lazy reference to a django model class, i can't seem to make it work here

```
class QuestionAnsweringModelResultsSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    answers = AnswerAnsweringModelResultsSerializer(many=True)
    images = QuestionAnsweringModelImagesResultsSerializer(many=True)
    written_answer_marking_settings = QuestionMarkingSettingsSerializer()
    parent_question = QuestionResultsSerializer()
    procedural_answers = ProceduralAnswerAnsweringSerializer(many=True)

     # the field below makes reference to the class below
    fill_in_the_blanks_answers = FillInTheBlanksAnsweringModelResultsSerializer(many=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = QuestionAnsweringModel
        fields = '__all__'


class FillInTheBlanksAnsweringModelResultsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  # the field below makes reference to the class above
    question = QuestionAnsweringModelResultsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = FillInTheBlanksAnsweringModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

I get the error a `class is not defined error`
where class is the name of the Serializer Class

Comment: It makes no sense to have two serializer refer to each other, since this will end up in infinite recursive responses.

Comment: Here, it does make sense.
The Logic functionality depends on them referring to each other

Comment: It would result in a `FillInTheBlanksAnsweringModelResultsSerializer` that produces a JSON with as field question that will contain a list of all related answers that will contain questions that will contain a list of all related answers that will contain a ...